# Running Android emulator Hyper-V based on a Azure VM Windows Server 2016

Tags: azure, android-emulator, appium, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

Our goal is to run UI tests with Appium on our CI build. But it seems that running the Android emulator (Hyper-V based) within virtual build machine (Windows Server 2016) on Azure might not be supported.

So my question is, does Hyper-V based nested virtualization is supported from a Windows Server 2016 virtual machine on Azure ?

note: using a CPU Android emulation is not an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you need to be on Dv3 or Ev3 SKU.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization

Comment: Is this possible? I tried and having issues setting it up. Did you have luck on yourself?